# file loading error

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, user-accounts

Okay so i'm trying to load up a bunch of profiles through C# and I keep getting this error when I try to start up the program.

```
C:\C#FILES>program.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the boun
ds of the array.
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.loadAccounts()
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args)

C:\C#FILES>
```

i've investigated and i think it has to do with the format of the accounts in the file
i'm wondering what the proper way is, i've tried every way i can think of

here's the loading accounts method

```
private static void loadAccounts()
{
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("accounts.txt"))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] details = line.Split('\t');
            accounts.Add(details[0] + ":" + details[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

the accounts.txt part is the part i'm unsure about, i thought it would be as follows
username(tab)password
like this

```
username    password
```

however it gives the error shown above
does anyone know what the proper account format should be?

Comment: I'm missing something... have you checked the file in an editor? Either details[0] or details[1]  doesn't exist., does the data actually existin the format as it reads the file? How about printing the line out as you go so you know which one it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an IndexOutOfRangeException, which suggests that `details` only had a single entry - which means there wasn't a tab on that line.

I suggest you print out the line in question *before* splitting, so you can see which line is causing problems. Or possibly do it conditionally:

```
while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    String[] details = line.Split('\t');
    if (details.Length == 1)
    {
        // Or log it, or whatever...
        Console.WriteLine("Input error: no tab in line '{0}'", line);
    }
    else
    {
        accounts.Add(details[0] + ":" + details[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because the line you are splitting from your input does not contain the elements requested.

It is unlikely that the first (read: `0`th) element in the array is the cause of the issue because of the way that .NET deals with `Split`.

Have you check that there are no blank lines in your input file? A single blank line (even at the end of the file) would cause this issue.

There are multiple checks you could add such as..

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)) ...
```

or

```
if(details.Length > 1)
```

These are a few checks, either or both I would recommend implementing (there are more to consider) otherwise you are just blindly trusting input values and that is not good practice in general.